# what is the exception when we overriding a method

Tags: java

I am new in Java ,i have a question ,what is the exception allows to use when i override a method ,what are  checked exception and what  are the unchecked exception, and can i use checked exceptions in overriding ?

Comment: What sources, web pages, google searches have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried google but i cant find anything

Comment: Googling is so important a method that I recommend you to try again to improve you google ability.

Comment: Googling for "Java Tutorial" leads to http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html, which is a good start.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Method overriding and exceptions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5875414/method-overriding-and-exceptions)

Comment: @finnw it's the same of my problem thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For questions like these please use google. Here's a link for you that might help.

http://www.javabeat.net/tips/133-handle-exceptions-in-overriding-methods.html

Answer (score 0):

You can not use checked exceptions in overriding, you can only use them if the overrided method is also using them.

Checked exceptions are subclasses of "Exception", they have to be caught or thrown by the method, and in general they represent invalid conditions in the program.

Unchecked exceptions are subclasses of "RuntimeException", they do not have to be caught or thrown by the method, and in general they represent defects/errors in your program.