# Why is it that an overridden method can't throw a new checked Exception

Tags: java

I have two questions :

1. What is the purpose of the constraint that an overridden method can't throw a new checked exception?
2. Why it is allowed that an overridden method can only throw all or none, or a subset of the checked exceptions that are specified in the throws clause of the overridden method in the superclass?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5875455/828625

Answer (score 9):

In both cases, it's because the base method you're overriding has set the contract with the calling code; if you could add to the checked exceptions that the method may throw, you'd be breaking the contract.

Consider a class `Base` with a method `foo` that throws a checked exception `SomeException`. You also have a `Derived` which derives from `Base` and overrides `foo`. Code in `App` is using a `Base b` variable but initializing it with a new instance of `Derived`, and calling `b.foo()`. The contract is that `foo` throws just `SomeException`; throwing anything else breaks the contract.

Answer (score 3):

Because of [the substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

In short: because you shouldn't surprise users of the class hierarchy with new behavior.

This principle is common to all OO design/languages, not specific to Java.

Answer (score 2):

An overriding class can add behavior and not remove. A method that declares to throw an exception - is a behavior.

Think what will happen if you have classes `A` and `B extends A`.

 `A` implements `foo() throws MyException`, and `B` implements `foo() throws OtherException`

What will

```
A a = new B();
a.foo();
```

have to catch?

However, if `B.foo()` throws only a subset of the exceptions - it is still perfectly safe, the calling environment will catch (or declare as throwing) all of `A`'s thrown exception - and by doing so - it will also deal with all of B's.

Answer (score 2):

Lets say it is possible to add new thrown exceptions in overridden methods.

```
class AA{
    void method() throws FileNotFoundException{}
}
class BB extends AA{
    @Override
    void method() throws FileNotFoundException, UnsupportedEncodingException {}
}
```

Now you create reference AA to object BB and call method

```
AA a=new BB();
try {
    a.method();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Compilator will let you catch only `FileNotFoundException` exception, and wont allow to catch `UnsupportedEncodingException` because it is called from reference AA.

But you can add few types of exceptions to overridden method

- if they are subtype of already thrown exception (`IOException` -> `IOException, FileNotFoundException`) because they will be checked,
- if new exception doesn't have to be checked -> all `RuntimeException`s