# What is the criteria for throwing exceptions in subclass

Tags: java, exception, polymorphism, overriding

What I have known till now is that a subclass if overriding a superclass method should throw the same exception or a subclass of the exception.

For example:

**This is correct**

```
class SuperClass {
    public int doIt(String str, Integer... data)throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException{
 String signature = "(String, Integer[])";
 System.out.println(str + " " + signature);
 return 1;
 }
}

public final class SubClass extends SuperClass {
    public int doIt(String str, Integer... data) throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException {
        String signature = "(String, Integer[])";
        System.out.println("Overridden: " + str + " " + signature);
        return 0;
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        SuperClass sb = new SubClass();
        try {
            sb.doIt("hello", 3);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
```

**This is Incorrect**

```
class SuperClass {
    public int doIt(String str, Integer... data)throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException{
 String signature = "(String, Integer[])";
 System.out.println(str + " " + signature);
 return 1;
 }
}

public final class SubClass extends SuperClass {
    public int doIt(String str, Integer... data) throws Exception {
        String signature = "(String, Integer[])";
        System.out.println("Overridden: " + str + " " + signature);
        return 0;
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        SuperClass sb = new SubClass();
        try {
            sb.doIt("hello", 3);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
```

**But my question is, why this code block is considered correct by compiler?**

```
class SuperClass {
    public int doIt(String str, Integer... data)throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException{
 String signature = "(String, Integer[])";
 System.out.println(str + " " + signature);
 return 1;
 }
}

public final class SubClass extends SuperClass {
    public int doIt(String str, Integer... data) throws RuntimeException {
        String signature = "(String, Integer[])";
        System.out.println("Overridden: " + str + " " + signature);
        return 0;
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        SuperClass sb = new SubClass();
        try {
            sb.doIt("hello", 3);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because in Java every method can throw a `RuntimeException` (or an `Error`) at any time. It does not even need to be declared in the `throws` part of your method signature. So it is possible to also throw a exception which is a super type of the one declared in your overridden method, as long it is still a sub type of `RuntimeException`.

See [Chapter 11 (Exceptions) of the Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-11.html) for the specification for this behavior, especially [11.1.1. The Kinds of Exceptions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-11.html#jls-11.1.1) which defines *checked* (needs to be specified in `throws` clause) and *unchecked* (does not need to be specified in `throws`clause) exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

When you override a method, you should define the same checked exceptions. In this case, the `SuperClass#doIt` method declares that throws an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, so every children that override that method should declare the same checked exceptions or its subclasses.

More info:

- [Method overriding and exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5875414/method-overriding-and-exceptions).

Comment: Does it mean, if a Runtime exception is thrown by the superclass method, any superclass in the exception hierarchy can be thrown.

Comment: Exception --> RuntimeException --> IndexOutOfBoundException --> ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException

Comment: Yes, that is correct. The exception declared in the override must be in its descendant tree, it can't be bigger than the exception declared in the super class.

Comment: @BugMeNot RuntimeException isn't a checked exception, that's the reason it works.

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza,thats correct.But why this rule is enforced by java.I wanted to know the reason behind it?

Answer (score 1):

To make an attempt to make it simple, [RuntimeException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html) and [Error](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Error.html) don't need to be declared in `throws` clauses, but are *always implied*. If you include the implied exceptions in the declaration, your superclass method declaration could be written;

```
public int doIt(String str, Integer... data)
    throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, Error, RuntimeException {
```

That means, the explicit RuntimeException declaration on the subclass method is a subclass of an existing (implied) exception on the superclass method, so it's allowed.

Answer (score 0):

If super class method does not declare any exception, then sub class overridden method cannot declare "checked" exception but it can declare "unchecked" exceptions