# Callable: why can we "change" the exception on implementation?

Tags: java, exception

This code compiles without an error:

```
private FutureTask<MessageSource> loadingTask(final Locale locale)
{
    return new FutureTask<MessageSource>(new Callable<MessageSource>()
    {
        @Override
        public MessageSource call()
            throws IOException
        {
            return loader.load(locale);
        }
    });
}
```

But the `Callable` interface defines this:

```
public V call()
    throws Exception;
```

How come I can declare that my override throws `IOException`?

Note: I have already seen, and exploited that, with Guava's `CacheLoader` for instance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5875414/method-overriding-and-exceptions

Answer (score 4):

The short answer: you can do that because an `IOException` is-a `Exception`.

```
public V call() throws Exception
```

means "this method can throw an `Exception` and no other checked exception!".

If you now override this method like this:

```
public MessageSource call() throws IOException
```

You're effectively saying "we would be allowed to throw any `Exception` but we voluntary restrict ourself to just a subset: `IOException` and its children".

You could even do this:

```
public Something call()
```

with no `throws` at all: "we would be allowed to throw any `Exception`, but I promise that we throw no checked exceptions at all!"

Answer (score 2):

When overriding a method that throws some exceptions, the overriden method must throw the same exceptions as the overriding method or some of their superclasses.

This is described in the [JLS #8.4.8.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.3):

> suppose that `B` is a class or interface, and `A` is a superclass or superinterface of `B`, and a method declaration `n` in `B` overrides or hides a method declaration `m` in `A`. Then:
>
> - If `n` has a `throws` clause that mentions any checked exception types, then `m` must have a throws clause, or a compile-time error occurs.
> - For every checked exception type listed in the throws clause of `n`, **that same exception class or one of its supertypes must occur in the erasureof the `throws` clause of `m`**; otherwise, a compile-time error occurs.

(where `n` overrides `m`)