# Throw Error, Exception and Runtime Exception in child class

Tags: java

I'm trying to understand the difference why a child class cannot override a method implementation in the parent class to catch an Exception but no problem while catching a Error,

For example in the below scenario, when I remove "Exception" from the throws clause, it compiles fine.

```
class Supertest {

    public void amethod(int i, String s) {

    }

}

public class test extends Supertest {

    public void amethod(int i, String s) throws Error, Exception {

    }

}
```

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5875414/method-overriding-and-exceptions

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Error` is an unchecked exception. `Exception` is a [checked exception](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catchOrDeclare.html). It's as simple as that. So it should be reasonable to have code like this:

```
Supertest x = new test();
x.amethod(10, "foo");
```

... but `test.amethod()` tries to impose a checked exception on the caller, so that the caller either has to catch it or propagate it. As the method it's overriding doesn't declare that exception, the overriding method can't either.

As noted in comments, fundamentally you can't override one method with a "more restrictive" one - any call to the original method must still be valid to the override.

From [section 8.4.8.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.1) of the JLS:

> More precisely, suppose that B is a class or interface, and A is a superclass or superinterface of B, and a method declaration n in B overrides or hides a method declaration m in A. Then:
>
> - If n has a throws clause that mentions any checked exception types, then m must have a throws clause, or a compile-time error occurs.
> - For every checked exception type listed in the throws clause of n, that same exception class or one of its supertypes must occur in the erasure (§4.6) of the throws clause of m; otherwise, a compile-time error occurs.

Comment: @OP throws clause apart, in general you cannot impose greater restriction on the overridden method. This includes changing return type from say `Integer` to `Number`.

Comment: Indeed - or change a method parameter from `Number` to `Integer`.

Comment: I guess changing parameter type will be compilable, and considered as Method overloading.

Comment: @RohitJain: It depends on whether you use `@Override` :) (But yes, they're fundamentally different to return types in that they're part of the signature. My bad. I'd thought Java had contravariant parameters in some places, but that's just my poor memory.)

Answer (score 2):

Throw clauses must be covariant.

This is similar to the requirement of return types of overriding methods:

```
SuperClass
    Pet method()

SubClass
    Cat method()
```

here `Cat` is a subtype of `Pet`, therefore the overriding is legal.

The same principle applies to `throws` clause, which is also part of the output of the method.

```
SuperClass
    Pet method() throws PetException

SubClass
    Cat method() throws CatException
```

this is legal if `CatException` is a subtype of `PetException`.

If the throw clause of a method is empty, it is implicitly `RuntimeException|Error`. All overriding methods must only throw subtypes of that. `Excepiton|RuntimeException|Error` is not a subtype of `RuntimeException|Error`.

Answer (score 0):

Say you have

```
SuperTest superTest = new test();
superTest.amethod();
```

at compile time, methods are resolved with the declared or static type of the variable. The `SuperTest#amethod` is declared without throwing the checked exception `Exception` so its children need to follow those rules.

`Error` is an unchecked exception. It doesn't need to be caught. As such the parent method declaration doesn't restrict it.

Answer (score 0):

> If super class method doesn't declare any exception then subclass overridden method cannot declare any checked exception.

Here is `Exception` is checked and `Error` is unchecked.So you can't throw `Exception`.
Reference http://www.javatpoint.com/exception-handling-with-method-overriding