# Throw an exception from an overridden method of a Java class

Tags: java, oop, exception, polymorphism, overriding

I want to extend Java's `HashMap<K, V>` class. I override the `put(...)` method and I want to throw an exception in some cases.

Since the base class's `put` method doesn't throw an exception, I get a compiler error.

What is the best solution for this?

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5875414/why-cant-overriding-methods-throw-exceptions-broader-than-the-overriden-method

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create in your sub-class a method that doesn't override `put`, but calls the original `put()` if necessary. Such method will be allowed to throw any exception you wish.

Or you can throw one of the unchecked exceptions that `put` already may throw (`UnsupportedOperationException`, `ClassCastException`, `NullPointerException`, `IllegalArgumentException`) or any other unchecked exceptions (though that would be less recommended, since they won't be documented in the `Map` interface).

From `Map::put` Javadoc :

> **Throws:**
>
> **UnsupportedOperationException** - if the put operation is not supported by this map
>   **ClassCastException** - if the class of the specified key or value prevents it from being stored in this map
>   **NullPointerException** - if the specified key or value is null and this map does not permit null keys or values
>   **IllegalArgumentException** - if some property of the specified key or value prevents it from being stored in this map

Comment: The logical option would be to wrap your exception in an `UnsupportedOperationException` and throw it. Like `throw new UnsupportedOperationException(yourException)`

Comment: Thanks! That's what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

You can always throw an Exception derived from `RuntimeException`.