# Invoking overriding method that throws Checked exception

Tags: java, exception, overriding

After reading [Why can't overriding methods throw exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5875414/why-cant-overriding-methods-throw-exceptions-broader-than-the-overridden-method), I understand that if method declared as throws a Checked exception, the overriding method in a subclass can only declare to throw that exception or its subclass:

```
class A {
   public void foo() throws IOException {..}
}

class B extends A {
   @Override
   public void foo() throws SocketException {..} // allowed

   @Override
   public void foo() throws SQLException {..} // NOT allowed
}
```

So because `SocketException` IS-A `IOException` I can declare the overriding method as throws any of subclass of `IOException`.

In my program, I want to invoke the overriding method declared as throws `FileNotFoundException` IS-A `IOException`. also handled with a try-catch block

```
import java.io.*;
class Sub extends Super{
    public static void main (String [] args){
        Super p = new Sub();
        try {
            p.doStuff();
        }catch(FileNotFoundException e){

        }
    }
    public void doStuff() throws FileNotFoundException{}
}

class Super{
    public void doStuff() throws IOException{}
}
```

But I am getting that compile-time error:
[image: Screenshot]

```
Sub.java:6: error: unreported exception IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
                    p.doStuff();
                             ^
```

What is the reason for that? I'm a little confused because everything that the Base class has also available to the subclasses.

Also much more confusing is the ability to catch `Exception` and `Throwable` In addition to `IOException` (The opposite from Overriding concept).

Comment: Some people may have images blocked. Can you also copy paste the compilation error in your question.

Comment: @CKing added right now

Comment: Just change `Super p = new Sub();` to `Sub p = new Sub();`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> What is the reason for that? I'm a little confused because everything that the Base class has also available to the subclasses.

You need to catch an `IOException` and not a `FilenotFoundException`. This is because of the fact that while the `doStuff` method from the subclass will be called at runtime, the compiler doesn't know about this yet. It only knows about the `doStuff` method in the super class which declares that it `throws` an `IOException`.

To address your edit : The `catch` block can chose to catch the exact exception that is expected in the `try` block or it can chose to catch a superclass of the exception. The reasoning behind this has got nothing remotely to do with method overriding.

Answer (score 14):

Your object reference is of type `Super`, even though you know it's a `Sub` object at runtime.  Therefore the compiler is checking the method definition of the `Super` and giving you this compile error.

It would be no different from getting the following compiler error:

```
Object o = new String("Hello World");
o.charAt(2); //Obviously not allowed
```

It's important to remember that the `throws` clause is part of the method definition.

Comment: But, java.lang.Object don't have `charAt` method While both `Super` and `Sub` has

Comment: Agreed.  However the principal is exactly the same, the compiler only checks that the methods you are calling are on the reference type (`Object` in my example, `Super` in your case).

Answer (score 5):

The compiler doesn't consider the type of the object, but the type of reference you are using which is `Super`.

As `Super.doStuff() throws IOException`, this is what you must catch.

BTW I highly recommend using an IDE, you will find it more productive.

Comment: How come I can use also `Exception` and `Throwable` In addition to `IOException`? 
That's opposite from Overriding that can only declare to throw that exception or its subclass

Comment: @Pau the overridden method cannot throw these but you can catch them

Answer (score 3):

By declaring p as Super

```
Super p = ...
```

your Compiler only knows `p` is some kind of `Super`. `Super`'s `doStuff()` throws an `IOException`, but your code catches only a special case of `IOException`, the `FileNotFoundException`. If you want to tell your Compiler this is definetly a `Sub` and not a `Super` just declare `p` as `Sub`.

In this case it's explicit not declared as `Sub` but as `Super` so any `Super` or its Childs might occur and throw any `IOException` which might not be a `FileNotFoundException` or any of it's childs.

Answer (score 2):

That's because you are using an object of static type Super.
The compiler can not know that at runtime p is pointing to a Sub object, so it wants to catch the exceptions thrown by the method declared in the Super class

Answer (score 2):

Because it makes checks by declared type, in this case `Super`.

It is not known (or checked) that your `p` will contain only instances of `Sub`. Also, it would not make sense to define a superclass variable and use it only and only for 1 particular subclass.

So your `Super p` contains instance of a `Super.class`. Its method `doStuff()` can throw everything that extends `IOException`, lets say `UnsupportedEncodingException`, but you try-catch only for `FileNotFoundException`, so that `Unsupported...` may have been thrown and must be handled.