# Not able to throw exception from onFailure of the okhttp callback

Tags: android, retrofit, okhttp

When I try to throw to exception from onFailure method Android Studio forces me to add try catch block and not allowing to throw exception to calling function.

```
protected void createUser(final UserRegister user) throws ApiException, RuntimeException {

    Call call = dbApi.registerUserAsync(user, new ApiCallback<UserRegistered>() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(ApiException e, int i, Map<String, List<String>> map) {
            Timber.e("Exception in createUser: " + e.getMessage());
            throw e;
        }
```

Comment: It's because you are overriding the `onFailure` method, and it doesn't throw an exception to begin with. Try adding `throws ApiException` to `onFailure` and read the error.

Comment: Yeah tried that Android studio doesn't allow to add throws ApiException to onFailure method

Comment: Exactly, so the error explains why Android "forces" you to add a try/catch block and doesn't allow you to throw an error. Although, you can throw a `RunTimeException`, `IllegalArgumentException` and other unchecked exceptions, refer [here](https://www.javatpoint.com/exception-handling-with-method-overriding).

Comment: I still get an error 
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: OkHttp Dispatcher
    Process: com.***.myapplication, PID: 27761
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed network call

Comment: You get it when you add `throw RuntimeException` to the method?

Comment: Yes I tried throw RuntimeException("Failed network call") and added ```throws RuntimeException``` to onFailure I got the above error

Comment: put `throws new RuntimeException("Failed network call")`

Comment: Yeah actually tried ```throw new  RuntimeException("Failed network call")``` but posted wrong in the above comment.

Comment: I got confused I think :) Just add inside the method `throw new RuntimeException("Failed network call")` and that's it, or in your method signature add `throws RuntimeException`, one or the other.

Comment: Tried both separately but it didn't work.

Comment: So, it goes inside the `onFailure` method, and throws the exception?

Comment: Goes inside onFailure actually not throwing exception to the calling function instead crashes with E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: OkHttp Dispatcher Process: com.***.myapplication, PID: 27761 java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed network call

Comment: Something I'm missing then, throwing unchecked exceptions should work, checkout [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5875414/why-cant-overriding-methods-throw-exceptions-broader-than-the-overridden-method) post, it should help.