# (Java) Thread Inexplicably Stalling at an Exception Catch

Tags: java, multithreading, exception, try-catch

I'm stuck in the middle of a real headscratcher here. My program gets to a point where it's supposed to throw an Exception and have it caught by it's parent process, except somewhere in there, the Thread seems to simply stop functioning and I can't explain why.

My program is very complex, but here is the essence of my problem {

```
public class ClassOne {

    public CustomClass computeCustomClass() throws IOException {
        //CustomClass is an elsewhere defined valid class in my code.
        try {
            //The core code of this "computeCustomClass" operation has the
            //potential of throwing a "CustomException", an Exception class
            //of my own creation.
        } catch (CustomException e){
            //I have inserted a logging utility here and it is logging that
            //this "catch" process is definitely being executed.
            //I will now wrap the CustomException in an IOException, as the
            //core code of "createCustomClass()" has the potential to generate
            //it's own IOExceptions, and the handling of a CustomException should
            //be done just the same by a parent process as if an IOException had
            //occurred.
            throw new IOException(e);
        }
    }
}

public class ClassTwo {

    private ClassOne myObject;

    public void processData(){
        try{
            //I've inserted a logging code here to track when this line is
            //executed.
            CustomClass data = myObject.computeCustomClass();
            //Another bit of logging code goes here and records when the
            //"computeCustomClass()" request goes off without a hitch.

            // Code goes here that processes the "data" variable;

        } catch (IOException e){
            //There is logging code here, but it NEVER records this "catch"
            //section being executed! Even when the "CustomException" catcher
            //in ClassOne.computeCustomClass() is logged as having executed!
            //It's as if the thread running this code abruptly stops without
            //throwing any exceptions/errors or any indication as to what's
            //occurred!
        }
    }
}
```

To make matters all the more confusing, I have another thread that runs concurrently to the one that executes the above code. One of this second thread's jobs is to post regular logs about the other thread. Even after whatever occurs that prevents the "catch IOException" code from executing, the thread that SHOULD be executing it reports a "true" value for "isAlive()", and a "false" value for "isInterrupted()".

I don't know what's happening. Any ideas why it might be stalling here, or can somebody suggest a way of diagnosing what the failure actually is?

Comment: Take a look at [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6546193/how-to-catch-an-exception-from-a-thread). Looks like exception handling in a concurrent situation is a little different.

Comment: I don't think it's the same issue. The second thread I mention doesn't actually run any of the code above or try to catch any exceptions generated within it. It merely (for the purposes of this problem) logs constant reports on the thread that IS executing the code I detail above, nothing more. And those reports, as I explained , keep stating that the problem thread is still alive and isn't interrupted. Besides, the IOException should never get to the thread's uncaught exception handler, because it's enclosed in a try/catch section that should handle it itself.

Comment: Have you tried broadening the catch in processData() of ClassTwo? It could be that a different exception gets thrown somehow and slips by the "catch (IOException e)". To let nothing get by, use "catch (Throwable e)"

Comment: Yes, in addition to the IOException catch, I've added a "Throwable" catch that likewise should be logged if it is executed. But it never is. Even if this was an incident of some uncaught exception, I should still be seeing reports of that being generated in the command prompt, like I do for other uncaught Exceptions/Errors I encounter.

Comment: Can any part of your custom exception throw an exception? Especially a runtime exception. Perhaps the wrapping process calls it's `toString` which could cause a truckload of grief if it throws perhaps an NPE.

Comment: @Cambot Are you sure that the `IOException` is actually being thrown? And what happens if you stick unchecked exceptions immediately before the `IOException` and immediately following the `catch` declaration?

Comment: @ OldCurmudgeon, no I doubt the custom exception could be generating a runtime exception itself. Besides, uncaught Runtime Exceptions leave evidence of themselves. i.e. in the command prompt.<br>@user3580294, I don't know if it's actually being thrown, all I know is that the line immediately before the line that says "throw IOException" is definitely being executed. And yes, I trust my logging code to execute without failing/throwing anything itself.

Comment: Step by step debugging will help you out here. On a side note, use @UserName when replying to someone's comment if you want them to be notified of it.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon "catch (Throwable e)" will catch anything, including runtime exceptions

Comment: I just ran a trial run where the "CustomException" isn't caught and wrapped but rather thrown by by the "computeCustomClass" process, then I copy/pasted the protocol for handling an IOException within the "processData()" call into a "CustomException" handler. Not it works perfectly! Looks like my issue had something to do with wrapping the exception in an IOException. I thought I could be a bit lazy and handle everything in a single catch protocol, but all things considdered, this is a pretty simple way to solve the problem. Thanks for all the input, guys! :D

Comment: @schmop - This is why I recommended it as a temporary measure to see if the catch is being avoided by a runtime exception.

Comment: Why are you looking for just `Thread.isAlive()` to determine *whether* it hangs when can look at `Thread.getStackTrace()` to find out *where* it hangs?

Answer (score 1):

I see from [grepCode](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Throwable.java#Throwable.%3Cinit%3E%28java.lang.Throwable%29) that constructing an exception with a cause actually calls the `toString()` method on the cause.

If your custom exception has a `toString()` method that could throw an exception or cause some significant time delay then this could be a source of your problem.

You could also - temporarily - use:

```
//} catch (IOException e){
} catch (Throwable e){
```

just in case you catch block is being bypassed.

Comment: You're right. Considering the OP stated that he tried to catch all throwables, there's no other explanation than an infinite loop or very lengthy operation in the toString() of CustomException - well, except a bug in the OP's specific JRE or a mistake in his reporting of the problem. This answer should be accepted.