# Errors are fatal in nature.... for process or for thread?

Tags: java, mysql, multithreading, exception, hsqldb

In my program there are 3 threads. `Thread 1` is responsible for populating records from MYSQL database which has currently 279381 records into queue. `Thread 2` and `Thread 3` read and process records from queue and insert them into the HSQL database. As per my expectoration, I got `OutOfMemoryError` on `Thread 1` but to my surprise instead of terminating my process, my `Thread 3` is still running. 
Isn’t it a weird behavior?
I always thought that `Errors` are fatal. They are at `jvm` level and program gets terminated on their occurrence. But I think that `Errors` are Thread specific and If program can continue even on their occurrence, why we are not allowed to catch them ? 
Or there is still something about which I am unaware of? I expect experts will show some light on it.

I am attaching the console output.

```
LL populated :: 558759
Rows Read from Hospital Database ::279381
Total Rows in HSQL :: 119699    8931464
In Read HSQL
LL populated :: 558759Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.nio.CharBuffer.wrap(CharBuffer.java:369)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implWrite(StreamEncoder.java:265)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.write(StreamEncoder.java:125)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.write(OutputStreamWriter.java:207)
    at java.io.BufferedWriter.flushBuffer(BufferedWriter.java:129)
    at java.io.PrintStream.newLine(PrintStream.java:545)
    at java.io.PrintStream.println(PrintStream.java:807)
    at XXXX.readResultSet(XXXX.java:196)    
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
java.sql.SQLException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.fetchResult(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
    at YYYY.readHSQL(YYYY.java:203)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.result.Result.newErrorResult(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.StatementDMQL.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.executeCompiledStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.executeDirectStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.hsqldb.QuerySpecification.buildResult(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.QuerySpecification.getSingleResult(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.QuerySpecification.getResult(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.StatementQuery.getResult(Unknown Source)
    ... 10 more

In Read HSQL
Total Rows in HSQL :: 119699    8931464
In Read HSQL
Total Rows in HSQL :: 119699    8931464
In Read HSQL
```

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing magical about thrown `Error`s, except they means something serious has happened, like out of memory. You you don't usually want to catch them, that's it.

Uncaught exceptions thrown inside a thread stops the thread itself. Other threads are not affected. There is a way to catch them though, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6546193/how-to-catch-an-exception-from-a-thread).