# Java - What happens when child thread dies from NPE , does parent thread get killed

Tags: java, android, multithreading, thread-safety

I have a main thread in android and it has spawned a child thread(an intentService but it doesn't really matter its just a thread). Lets say the child thread gets a uncaught null pointer exception then my question is does the main thread die or only the child thread ? can the process continue ?

Comment: There is no parent-child relationship in the context of executing a thread.

Comment: i know but what happens to the process, can it continue then ? does the JVM halt the program and crash or does it continue

Comment: spawning a thread does not halt the main thread from running. they should run concurrently

Comment: thats not my question coffeeaddict.  im asking if a secondary thread gets any NPE can the program continue or does it die ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6546193/how-to-catch-an-exception-from-a-thread

Comment: from your link ajb it seems the main thread continues and process lives, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a thread exits due to an error, the JVM will continue execution as long as there exists other non-daemon threads. Daemon threads are like normal threads, but do not keep the JVM alive if there only daemon threads still alive. The JVM usually keeps a lot of daemon threads around, including the GC and finalizer threads, to do maintenance and process signals from the OS.