# Try-Catch for runOnUiThread

Tags: android, exception, try-catch, android-runonuithread

I want to catch some exception through my code, the code hierarchy is like the following:

```
    try {
        // some code 1
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // some code 2
            }
        });

        // some code 3
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // some code 4
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }
```

But when running like that, it doesn't catch any exception of  `some code 2` and `some code 4` which are inside `runOnUiThread`, and the only way to catch them is to have a `try-catch` block inside `runOnUiThread` to catch them:

```
    try {
        // some code 1
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    // some code 2
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
        });

        // some code 3
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    // some code 4
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }
```

So, is `runOnUiThread` actually needs this? or I'm doing something wrong? and if it's already needs this, is there is some way to globally achieve this rather than a `try-catch` inside each `runOnUiThread` code block?

Comment: First of all, why do you need runOnUiThread() at all? What exceptions are you catching?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6548203/2197087 See this answer

Comment: @Egor It's an app which UI changes according to regular server responses, and these responses require a lot of parsing and processing at first to extract the info needed, So, I made all the parsing and processing in a background thread and ran the UI thread for the UI changes only.

Comment: @IvanSkoric I know about catching the uncaught exceptions and I'm using it in my app but in fact I don't want to make the app reloads from begging (this is the action I'm using when catch uncaught exception) every time I receive an Exception from this class in specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So, is runOnUiThread actually needs this?

yes, when you use the `runOnUiThread` you *may* run on a different processing thread. That means that every exception thrown inside the `Runnable` *may* be thrown on a different thread than the one where you put your try.

> is there is some way to globally achieve this rather than a try-catch
>   inside each runOnUiThread code block?

Having a custom class extending `Runnable` that "Throws" a custom / any Exception, but that doesn't sound really comfortable to do.