# Java 5 Multi threading, catch thread exceptions

Tags: java, multithreading, exception, concurrency, java-5

I've got a class that generates threads (file i/o). I need to catch exceptions in the thread - I don't want to do anything fancy, I want to kill the main thread, rather, stop processing altogether so it can start over.

If I catch the exceptions in the thread, that's all good and well but the caller still proceeds, I want it to die.

I've had a few ideas but nothing is really getting me anywhere. What's the most succinct way to do this-CallBack, UnCaughtExceptionHandler? Something else?
 I am also relegated to Java 5

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6546193/how-to-catch-an-exception-from-a-thread

Comment: killing a thread IS fancy (or rather problematic).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most common approach is to submit a `Callable` to an `Executor`, and receive a `Future`. You can then call `Future.get` to find out if any exceptions were thrown.

As for `UncaughtExceptionHandler`, you can only really use it with raw threads because `Executor`s handle uncaught exceptions internally (thus you don't even see the uncaught exceptions in the handler!), and since you rarely want to use raw threads over `Executor`s, `Callable` is IMO the best bet.