# "Unreported exception" from method call despite catching esception

Tags: java, exception, try-catch, java-io

I recieve 3 errors in the following section of code:

```
public static void main(String[] args){

     CS_Socket cs = new CS_Socket();

     try{
         new Thread(() -> cs.EchoServer()).start();
         new Thread(() -> cs.EchoClient()).start();
       }

     catch(IOException e){

       System.out.println(e.getMessage());

     }
}
```

For both new threads, I receive `unreported exception java.io.IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown` as a compiler error.

In `catch(IOException e)`, I receive `exception java.io.IOException is never thrown in body of corresponding try statement`.

I'm new to Java and have no idea how to fix these errors. None of the other questions about these errors seem to contain answers relevant to my code.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Put your `try{` before the `CS_Socket` line, it is probably this line that may throw an `IOException` .

Comment: @Berger Nope, I still get the errors.

Comment: looks like `CS_Socket.EchoServer()` and `CS_Socket.EchoClient()` are the methods that need a `catch()` statement. It would help if you could post the code for class `CS_Socket`

Answer (score -1):

Exception thrown in a thread normally couldn't be caught in another thread.

See this link for more explanation [How to catch an Exception from a thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6546193/how-to-catch-an-exception-from-a-thread)

Comment: Please check the modified answer