# Why can't I see exception thrown out from java daemon thread

Tags: java, multithreading, exception, daemon

I wrote a piece of Java code to test thread, like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Thread t = new Thread(() -> {
                throw new NullPointerException();
        });
        t.setDaemon(true);
        t.start();
    }
```

I expected to see something like :

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.cisco.ruan.nio.Java8Time.lambda$0(Java8Time.java:23)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

But nothing is printed out, unless I commented `t.setDaemon(true);`.

My question is why there is no message when there is a exception popped up in a daemon thread. What is the purpose of such design?

Comment: Please search SO before asking: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6546193/how-to-catch-an-exception-from-a-thread

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because the `JVM` will exit before the exception is thrown, alternatively logged.

As quoted from https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setDaemon(boolean)

`The Java Virtual Machine exits when the only threads running are all daemon threads.`

Try doing a `Thread.sleep(1000)` right after `t.start()` to see if the message is logged.