# How to catch exceptions from indirect thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, exception

EDIT:

[How to catch an Exception from a thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6546193/how-to-catch-an-exception-from-a-thread) - this is not a duplication. The link refers to direct thread (son thread) which it's not the case here! We are talking about indirect (grandson thread). The son thread is a closed `JAR` (I do not have write access)

---

I have the following method: `f1` which I don't have write access to (It's a closed `JAR`).

`f1` creates and runs a task on new thread which throws exception. 
On the `main` method, I must call `f1` on new thread. I need to be able to catch all the exceptions which were thrown from child threads of `f1`.

In other words, how do I catch exceptions from `grandson` thread without changing the `son` thread.

```
main method opens new thread and call:
      |
      V
f1 method opens new thread and call:
      |
      V
anonymous method which throws exception
```

Example code:

```
private static void f1() {
    Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()
            .submit(() -> {
                try {
                    throw new Exception("exception from anonymous thread");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    throw e;
                }
            });

}

public void main() {
    final Future<?> submit = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()
            .submit(() -> f1());
    try {
        submit.get();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: ExecutionException will have the thrown exception as root cause

Comment: @GhostCat This is not the same question! Your duplication refers to directed thread (son thread) which it's not the case here! We are talking about indirect  (grandson thread)

Comment: @GhostCat The OP does not ask the same question. Your link refers to a question which has to write access to the code and here the OP doesn't have.

Comment: @ᴳᵁᴵᴰᴼ I checked, It does not.

Comment: @StavAlfi It does not because the method `f1` swallows all the exceptions, it doesn't throw any exception itself, that's why in the main method we can catch nothing.

Comment: @grape_mao do you imply that, in case I can't edit `f1`, there isn't any solution for this problem ?

Comment: @AlmaShvartz I can't say that for sure, maybe some hack on bytecode level. If the design of `f1` doesn't give you access to the executor/thread, nor to the task, then it doesn't want you to care about the execution. But for me it's a bad design.

Comment: No chance. Keep in mind that by the time, your `main` method’s `submit.get()` returns, there is no guaranty that the asynchronous task spawned by `f1()` has even finished, not to speak of having delivered an inspectable exception. Even `UncaughtExceptionHandler` of the linked answer won’t help, as the exception is not uncaught. When `submit` is used, the job gets wrapped in a future which will catch any exception, so it can be propagated if `get` is called. Since no-one keeps a reference to that future, the exception is lost. Without modifying `f1()`, there’s no way.

Answer (score 1):

There is no general answer to this question. In this case exception is handled inside Executor. You can do one of

- catch all exceptions that may occur inside task and return meaningfull status for exceptions caught
- if task was submitted as `Callable<?>` then `get` on returned `Future<?>` will  throw `ExecutionException`  if task completed with exception
- for uncaught exceptions you could set Uncaught Exception Handler on Thread Factory used by Executor
- ThreadPoolExecutor has `afterExecute(Runnable r, Throwable t)` method with can handle uncaught exceptions from tasks