# Handle exceptions on multiple running threads Java

Tags: java, multithreading, exception

I am developing a java app I would like to know how to handle exceptions on multiple running threads. Is there any example? Thanks

Comment: Have a look over http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8362345/defining-one-global-uncaughtexceptionhandler-for-all-threads-of-my-application

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6662539/java-thread-exceptions

There is a complete explanation and example code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you asking how to detect that thread finished due to unhandled exception.

You need to implement `UncaughtExceptionHandler` for that. The simplest useful activity you can put in your implementation of handler is to log exception which wasn't caught.

One sample of this, used together with `Executor`:

```
    final Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler DEFAULT_HANDLER = new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
        @Override
        public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
            log.error("", e);
        }
    };

    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool(new ThreadFactory() {
        @Override
        public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
            Thread t = new Thread(r);
            t.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(DEFAULT_HANDLER);
            return t;
        }
    });

    executorService.execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            throw new RuntimeException("log me");
        }
    });
```