# Assertion in threaded code doesnt fail testcases

Tags: java, multithreading, testng

I have written a multi thread code which will verify data in database and assert accordingly. But the assertions are not working in this environment.

Code to create threads

```
Runnable r = new WorkerThread(subasscociation);
new Thread(r).start();
new Thread(r).start();
```

The code for thread start function is

```
   public class WorkerThread implements Runnable {

    ArrayList<Association> alInsertedAssociations;
    public WorkerThread(ArrayList<Association> alInsertedAssociations) {
        this.alInsertedAssociations = alInsertedAssociations;
    }

    public void run() {
        SecondLevelVerification slv = new SecondLevelVerification();
        slv.verify(alInsertedAssociations,"add", false);
    }
}
```

The function which asserts

```
public void verify(...)
{
  //Code to check database
 org.testng.Assert.assertNotEquals(label, 0);
}
```

But the code doesn't seem to work ie it doesnt assert correctly if the database doesn't have that entry.

Comment: What's the multi-threaded part? We can't tell you why the test is failing if we can't see the code that you're testing.

Comment: multithreaded part is the verify function. This function reads from a arraylist and checks if the entry is available in database. I am spliting the array list and creating the thread.

Comment: Did you try your debugger?

Answer (score 4):

Assertions work by throwing an exception, which in your case doesn't reach the handler installed by the testing framework. The latter monitors only the thread in which the test was started, whereas the exception is thrown from a different thread (created from within the test). See these questions for more details:

- [How to catch an Exception from a thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6546193/how-to-catch-an-exception-from-a-thread)
- [java thread exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6662539/java-thread-exceptions)

The accepted answers therein suggest how to solve your problem. Here is a draft version of a class that will allow to propagate exceptions occurring inside your threads to the testing framework:

```
class MyThread extends Thread implements Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler {
    Throwable interceptedException = null;

    MyThread(Runnable r) {
        super(r);
        this.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable ex) {
        interceptedException = ex;
    }

    public void myjoin() throws Throwable {
        super.join();
        if ( interceptedException != null )
            throw interceptedException;
    }
}
```

Your will have to use `MyThread` instead of `Thread` in your test code and call the `myjoin()` method:

```
Runnable r = new WorkerThread(subasscociation);
final myThread1 = new MyThread(r);
final myThread2 = new MyThread(r);

myThread1.start();
myThread2.start();

...

myThread1.myjoin();
myThread2.myjoin();
```