# Is an abstract superclass garbage collected when the last instance of the subclass is collected?

Tags: java, static, garbage-collection, superclass, timertask

I have an abstract class which I use to expire instances of a subclass:

```
public abstract class Expirable {
    private transient Timer timer;

    protected abstract void onExpire();

    protected void setExpire(long delay) {
        resetExpire();

        timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                           @Override
                           public void run() {
                               resetExpire();
                               onExpire();
                           }
                       }, delay
        );
    }

    protected void resetExpire() {
        if (timer != null) {
            timer.cancel();
            timer = null;
        }
    }
}
```

I extend any class and overide `onExpire`, then I call `setExpire(delay)` from the subclass (not shown):

```
public class MyClass extends Expirable {
    @Override
    protected void onExpire() {
        // expiration code here
    }
}
```

This class works perfectly fine, but the `timer` object is very expensive. Because I have tens of thousands of instances, I wrote a cheap version with the same functionality, which uses a single `timer` scheduled at a fixed rate and a `queue`. Not as precise, but cheap.

```
public abstract class ExpirableCheap {
    private static final long COLLECTOR_INTERVAL_MSEC = 1000;
    private static final int INITIAL_CAPACITY = 128;

    private static Queue<ExpirableCheap> queue = new PriorityBlockingQueue<>(
            INITIAL_CAPACITY,
            Comparator.comparingLong(expirable -> expirable.expiresWhen)
    );

    @SuppressWarnings("FieldCanBeLocal")
    private static TimerTask timerTask;
    @SuppressWarnings("FieldCanBeLocal")
    private static Timer timer;
    static {
        timerTask = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // this Runnable stops working
                long time = new Date().getTime();
                while (queue.peek() != null && queue.peek().expiresWhen < time) {
                    queue.poll().onExpire();
                }
            }
        };
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask,
                COLLECTOR_INTERVAL_MSEC,
                COLLECTOR_INTERVAL_MSEC
        );
    }

    private transient long expiresWhen;

    protected abstract void onExpire();

    protected synchronized void setExpire(long delay) {
        resetExpire();

        long time = new Date().getTime();
        expiresWhen = time + delay;

        queue.offer(this);
    }

    protected synchronized void resetExpire() {
        queue.remove(this);
    }
}
```

Obviously, the static code block is executed once and schedules the `timer` in regular intervals. The `timerTask` peeks at the queue and calls `onExpire()`.

What's wrong?

This runs fine for a while, but then suddenly the `timerTask` is no longer executed. When testing, it works fine and I cannot simulate the situation, but it fails after some time in production.

I am not sure what happens, but I suspect the static variables which I initialized in the static code block are garbage collected when the last instance of the subclass is collected. Then, when the class is re-used, the static code block is not run again. In other words, it seems to work until there are no instances anymore which `extend ExpirableCheap`.

Strangely, the `queue` persists, reason why I expected an exception to happen inside the `Runnable`, which I believe is not the case.

As you can see, I tried to move `timer` and `timerTask` variables from the static code block into member variables (which didn't help). I also tried to synchronize `setExpire()` and `resetExpire()`, which I believe makes no difference either.

Can anybody see what's happening? Did I make another stupid mistake and am I on the wrong track?

Any suggestions what I could change to make this work?

Comment: I don't think that the JVM would normally garbage collect something which could again be referenced later in the code.

Comment: Are you sure it's not something going wrong in `onExpire`?

Comment: @user2357112 I have exception handing in the server, but I explicitly wrapped the code where `onExpire` is called into a try-catch block. Will get back to this.

Comment: It doesn't have to be an exception. `onExpire` could be hanging.

Comment: @user2357112 This was a good bet, thanks. It was an exception in `onExpire`, but it was swallowed and not bubbled up to the server-wide exception handler. I expected to see such exception in the logs or have the JVM crash, but this obviously is not the case. Interesting discussion here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11584159/is-there-a-way-to-make-runnables-run-throw-an-exception - Post as answer and I'll accept :)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen You were right, the abstract class was not garbage collected.

Comment: That’s one of the reasons why programmers should not use `java.util.Timer` and `TimerTask`; if an exception occurs, it will be swallowed and the task doesn’t get rescheduled. Use a [`ScheduledExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) instead. See also [`Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor())…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @TimBiegeleisen correctly pointed out, Java works as expected. An abstract superclass is NOT garbage collected when the last instance of the subclass is collected.

My problem was unrelated.