# handle java exception in Thread.run

Tags: java, exception

I have an inner class that extends Thread

```
private class TestStart extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        try {
            startServer();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            /// How to handle it?
        }
    }
}
```

The caller in the main thread:

```
public void start() throws Exception {
    Thread st = new TestStart();
    st.start();
}
```

Method startServer() throws Exception by its API, so I have to use try-catch as Thread.run() does not "throws" exception in method definition. I need to bubble up the caught exception into the main thread to handle it. Is there an easy way to do it? Thanks

Comment: How do you start these threads? If you were using an `ExecutorService`, you'd be able to submit a `Runnable` and get a `Future<?>`; calling `get()` on that `Future` would yield an `ExecutionException` if an exception were thrown in the `Runnable`.

Comment: See [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369204/how-to-throw-a-checked-exception-from-a-java-thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369204/how-to-throw-a-checked-exception-from-a-java-thread)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use an `ExecutorService` instead of using raw threads, you can be notified of uncaught exceptions:

```
class MyCallable implements Callable<Void> {
  @Override public Void call() throws Exception {
    // Do something - you don't need to catch Exception as Callable throws it.
    // ...

    return null;  // A return is necessary from a Callable.
  }
}
```

Create an executor service somewhere, e.g.:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
```

Then, in the code where you start the thread:

```
Future<?> future = executor.submit(new MyCallable());

try {
  future.get();  // Blocks until the Callable completes.
} catch (ExecutionException e) {
  // You reach here if an exception is thrown in the Callable -
  // The exception is accessible via e.getCause().
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a few possible solutions. For example:

1. Use setUncaughtExceptionHandler()/setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler() and change your try/catch

   ```
   try {
       startServer();
   }
   catch (RuntimeException e) {
       throw e;
   }
   catch (Exception e) {
       throw new RuntimeException(e);
   }
   ```
2. Or use your custom listener

   ```
   private class TestStart extends Thread {
       private final ServerStateListener lnr;

       TestStart(ServerStateListener lnr) {
           this.lnr = lnr;
       }

       public void run() {
           try {
               startServer();
               lnr.onServerStarted();
           }
           catch (Exception e) {
               lnr.onServerStoppedByError(e);
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. Or just save Exception and read it after .join

   ```
   private class TestStart extends Thread {
       private Exception error; // if you start and join and read this property within one thread, you don't need to use volatile, otherwise do it for safe publication

       public void run() {
           try {
               startServer();
           }
           catch (Exception e) {
               error = e;
           }
       }

       public Exception getError() {
           return error;
       }
   }
   ```
4. Or use ExecutorService/Callable instead of your own thread as Andy suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Set a new exception handler on your Thread.

```
   st.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.
             UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
               public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
               System.out.println(t + " throws exception: " + e);
             }
   });
```

And place that code before your start();